# rewrite rule to forward old search to new search

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, centos

I've search  for a few hours now but I can't figure out a solution. 
I just put up a new website that has a different search url than the old site. I'm trying to capture the search queries pointed at the old site and send them to the new sites search. 
such as:
advanced_search_result.php?search_in_description=1&keywords=alternator

redirecting to the new sites search like:
index.php?route=product/search&search=alternator

I've tried variations of the following without any luck.

```
RewriteRule ^advanced_search_result\.php?.*keywords=(.*)$ index.php?route=product/search&search=$1 [R=301,L]
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what does "without any lock" actually mean? What happens? Are you seeing a redirection at all? Is it wrong? Does it crash? Does the universe implode?

Comment: Make sure the http server process is able to read your dynamic configuration file, make sure the interpretation of such files is enabled at all (`AllowOverride` directive), check that you have the rewriting module enabled and use a `RewriteEngine on`, make sure the file is located in the right location on the right system and monitor your http servers log files.

Comment: And a general hint: in 99% of all cases it makes more sense to place such rewriting rules in the old hosts configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files.

Comment: It doesn't redirect at all.

Comment: I have other rewrite rules set in this same file that are working just fine.

Comment: The old host is no longer publicly available

Comment: It is the old host that has to redirect the search requests. If it is not publicly available any more, then requests to it will end into nirwana. No need to operate a host service requests to the old URL.

Comment: Oh and sorry, I just realize the issue you face is that you are trying to map a pattern _including_ the query string which is not possible with a `RewriteRule`. That is clearly documented. You need to use a `RewriteCond` for that. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to map a pattern including the query string which is not possible with a `RewriteRule`. That is clearly documented. You need to use a `RewriteCond` for that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:[^&]*&)*keywords=([^\&]*)
RewriteRule ^/?advanced_search_result\.php$ /index.php?route=product/search&search=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Reason is that in a `RewriteRule` the pattern is only matched against the *path* component of the request URL. The query string is *not* part of that. Matching against the query string is only possible in a `RewriteCond` using the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable, since such a condition can test an arbitrary string against some pattern, not only the path component of the URL. Tokens captured inside such a condition can then be cited by a `%1` in a following `RewriteRule`, as opposed to the `$1` which refers to a capture for that rule itself.

The details are explained in the [official documentation of the rewriting module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) which is something you should always consult when working on rewriting or redirection rules. It is very well written and comes with good examples.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you, can you please elaborate on how rewrite conditions work vs rewrite rules?

Comment: Thank you. This is making much more sense to me now. I have read some of the documentation but was getting confused. Last question, In your example, why is %1 used to reference the search string rather than %2?

Comment: Using your example, I'm getting redirection however it's incorrect. it's redirecting to:
/index.php?route=product/search&search=search_in_description=1

Comment: @StevenLutz I do have to apologize, I modified the answer once more, fixed the condition. The `%1` is correct, but for that to work the first bracket set has to be marked as a "non capturing group" (`(?:.....)`). I added that group later to gain more flexibility in your query string and forgot about that detail. I also fixed the second capture group, there was the circumflex missing in there (`^`)...

Comment: Thank you very much! This is working. 
I do have a much better understanding of how this all works now, however I don't understand why you created the first group if you don't intend on capturing it.. in other words, why put the first group in ( ) if you don't intent to reference it?
Also, why is the last group composed of [^\&]* rather than just grabbing everything (.*) ?

Comment: @StevenLutz The answer to both is precision: there might be other get arguments before or after the `keywords` argument, separated by an ampersand, or those might not be present. Without the leading group You either have to try `^keywords=...` which won't match if there is another argument before that (`test=1&keywords=...`) or you leave out the circumflex, but then things like ...?mykeywords=...` will be matched too which is not what you want. Similar for the last capture group: you definitely only want to capture until the next get argument starts.

Comment: Ah OK, this makes sense. Being that arguments are separated by & you're ensuring that only the keywords argument is captured. Excellent & thanks again!

Comment: @StevenLutz Yep, that is one half of the logic. The complex details is that those other arguments might not be there at all which is why you cannot simply use the `&` itself as anchor but have to make this _potential_.